# describe binding filtering in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, major-mode

Is there a way to filter the list of available bindings (<kbd>C-h b</kbd>), so it will not show all the possible bindings but just the relevant ones for the used mode?
For example on `org-mode`, I get all the general <kbd>C-x</kbd> list plus all the bindings of the modes that have general key bindings plus all the major mode bindings, followed by all the org mode ones, followed by global bindings... 1369 lines in total... I'm using this view for learning my way around, perhaps there is a way to filter so as to find my way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for <kbd>C-h m</kbd> which runs the command [`describe-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-Help.html).

You will find more goodies in <kbd>C-h C-h</kbd> which runs the command [`help-for-help`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Help.html).

Comment: that is very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. `C-h m` shows the doc for the current major mode, as well as currently enabled minor modes.

   Often `C-h m` lists some of the more important local key bindings, that is, some of the bindings made for the current major mode.  But not always, and typically it does not list all of the local bindings.
2. If you use library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) then you can use command `describe-keymap` to list all of the local key bindings:

   ```
   M-: (describe-keymap (current-local-map))
   ```

   If you know the name of the local keymap variable (e.g. `emacs-lisp-mode`) then you can invoke `describe-keymap` interactively using `C-h M-k`, providing the map name at the prompt.
3. If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can see all of the currently available key bindings using `S-TAB` ([key completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion)).  By default, the local bindings (i.e, those for the current major mode) are shown first, and are highlighted specially. (You can use `C-,` to sort the candidate bindings in other ways (by key name, prefix keys first; by command name).

Answer (score 0):

After <kbd>C-h b</kbd> switch into Help-buffer and call <kbd>M-x</kbd>`occur`<kbd>RET</kbd>org<kbd>RET</kbd> which will display all lines containing "org".